# Linux shell script to know if the directory (or file) has 777 permission

Tags: linux, shell

We give the upmost permission to a file or directory, using this command:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 directory
```

Now I want to know if this command is already executed for a given directory.

I know I can use `-r` for read, `-w` for write, and `-x` for execution, in `[ test ]` blocks.

But I want to know two things:

- Is it also a directory?
- Does it have those permissions for everyone?

How can I get that info?

**Update**

Based on @Barmar comment, I came up with this. But it's not working:

```
if [ stat /Temp | grep -oP "(?<=Access: \()[^)]*" == '' ]; then
    echo '/Temp folder has full access'
else 
    sudo chmod -R 777 /Temp
fi
```

This command works though:

```
stat /Temp | grep -oP "(?<=Access: \()[^)]*"
# prints => 0777/drwxrwxrwx
```

How should I fix the syntax error of my `if-else` statement?

Comment: Use the `stat` command, it can return lots of information about a file/directory.

Comment: @HosseinFallah : I don't know what you want to achieve with your `if`: It runs the command `[`  and not `stat`, and you should get an error message about a missing `]`. What would make sense is to do something like `if [[ $(stat ....) == '' ]]`, but  parsing the output of `ls -ld /Temp` would perhaps be simpler. While in the general case, parsing the stdout of `ls` discouraged, I don't see what would speak against it in your case.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to process the output of `stat` with `grep`; you can ask `stat` to only produce the specific information you want. See the man page regarding the `--format` option.  We can for example write:

```
# ask stat for the file type and mode, and put those values into $1
# and $2
set -- $(stat --format '%F %a' /Temp)

if [[ $1 == directory ]]; then
  if [[ $2 == 777 ]]; then
    echo "/Temp folder has full access"
  else
    sudo chmod -R 777 /Temp
  fi
else
  echo "ERROR: /Temp is not a directory!" >&2
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple example:

```
#!/bin/bash

function setfullperm(){
    [ -d $1 ] && \
    (
        [ "$(stat --format '%a' $1)" == "777" ] && \
            echo "Full permissions are applied." || \
            ( echo "Setting full permissions" && sudo chmod -R 777 $1 )
    ) || \
    ( echo "$1 is not a directory !" && mkdir $1 && setfullperm $1 )
}

export setfullperm
```

Source the script:

```
$ source example.sh
```

Set full permissions (777) on any directory, it tests if the directory exists in the first place, if not it will create it and set the permissions.

It will export the function `setfullperm` to the shell so you can run it:

```
>$ setfullperm ali
ali is not a directory !
mkdir: created directory 'ali'
Setting full permissions

>$ setfullperm ali
Full permissions are applied.
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend using stat for this. Though widespread, stat isn't POSIX, which means there's no guarantee that your script will work in the future or work on other platforms. If you're writing scripts for a production environment, I'd urge you to consider a different approach.

You're better off using ls(1)'s -l option and passing the file as an argument. From there you can use cut(1)'s -c option to grab the file mode flags.

Get file type:

```
ls -l <file> | cut -c1
```

Also, don't forget about test's -d operator, which tests if a file is a directory.

Get owner permissions:

```
ls -l <file> | cut -c2-4
```

and so on.

This approach is POSIX compliant and it avoids the shortcomings of using stat.

Comment: Should use '/bin/ls' to avoid aliasing.

Comment: @Rafael : Should be `ls -ld`, since the OP said that his `/Temp` is a directory.

Answer (score 1):

If using `zsh` (But not other shells), you can do it with just a glob pattern:

```sh
setopt extended_glob null_glob
if [[ -n /Temp(#q/f777) ]]; then
    echo '/Temp folder has full access'
else
    sudo chmod -R 777 /Temp
fi
```

The pattern `/Temp(#q/f777)` will, with the `null_glob` and `extended_glob` options set, expand to an empty string if `/Temp` is anything but a directory with the exact octal permissions 0777 (And to `/Temp` if the criteria are met). For more details, see [Glob Qualifiers](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) in the zsh manual.

Comment: I'd split up the is-a-directory and has-the-needed-permissions tests, though, for better error reporting. What if `/Temp` is an existing regular file?